# How to build a stopwatch that continues counting when app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, stopwatch

I tried building a stopwatch in Swift, which worked but it stops counting when one exits the app and only continues once you reopen it. I used:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(stopwatchFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Is there any way the stopwatch can continue counting even when the app is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Save both the current time and the timer’s time when the app is closed. You can use User Defaults, or whatever works for you. When it is opened again, use the current time to calculate the difference and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, you can't. To truly keep a timer running while your app is closed, your app would need to continue to receive processor time. Apple doesn't allow any but a very narrow group of apps to run indefinitely in the background (turn-by-turn navigation apps, music players, and VoIP apps)

@forot told you how to simulate it. (Voted.) If you get notified that your app is being suspended, save the current time and the time remaining somewhere like UserDefaults. When you come back, get the new current time, calculate how much time has elapsed, and update your timer accordingly.

If the timer expires while you are suspended/terminated there's nothing you can do.

You could set up local notifications to fire when your timer is due to go off. The user can then tap the notification and re-launch your app if they choose.